# How to know who created a Field Set

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I am currently unable to see who created a Field Set in Salesforce, I tried looking at the Schema.FieldSet class, but I couldn't find any details on createdBy

Map FsMap = 
    Schema.SObjectType.Account.fieldSets.getMap();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Tooling API query (from Developer Console, Workbench or another tool):

```
SELECT Id, DeveloperName, Description, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name
FROM FieldSet
```

should get you started (in dev console it's just a matter of ticking the checkbox on bottom of query editor; in workbench go to REST explorer menu).

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fieldset.htm

---

Alternatively some info might be visible in Setup Audit Trail (last 6 months you can download easily, you can also query the table although it's painful to filter it... https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_setupaudittrail.htm

---

**EDIT**

There's not-exactly-documented way to know to which sObject this fieldset belongs. Documentation of Fieldset object doesn't mention the existence of `EntityDefinitionId` field but if you go to [`EntityDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) in Tooling API you can see a very promising child relationship to `Fieldsets`. So... *undocumented, can break in future* but try this query

```
SELECT EntityDefinitionId, EntityDefinition.Namespaceprefix, EntityDefinition.DeveloperName, 
    Id, DeveloperName, Description, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name
FROM FieldSet
ORDER BY EntityDefinitionId, Id
```

[image: Sample Tooling API query results for Fieldset + parent sObject]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried it on workbench and it worked nicely, can I ask how to know in which object is that fieldset used ? or is there a way to know all the fields available to query ?

Comment: See the edit. once you know the object's name & fieldset name it should be easy to use "describe" calls to get the list of fields in each fieldset. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/how-to-get-fieldset-fields-in-apex-dynamically-fieldset-name-is-not-static for example. I don't think "FieldsetMember" is a table you can call normal or SOQL queries on...

Comment: Hello eyescream, it worked beautifully, I am trying to do a get Request from an external application instead of workbench and build a tool for my queries, I was thinking of MS Excel VBA, if I want to do a GET request in an external application - C# or Java or VB, do you have any idea how the endpoint should be set, for now I have created a connected app in salesforce, and I have a consumer key, a consumer secret and a Callback URL, the only way it's working now is on workbench REST /services/data/v40.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Id,DeveloperName,Description,CreatedDate,CreatedBy.Name+FROM+FieldSet

Comment: Not sure, I've made it work from Java and PHP few years ago but that was normal username + pass, not the more modern OAuth. Have a look at https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Consuming_Force.com_SOAP_and_REST_Web_Services_from_.NET_Applications (you'll have to scroll down for rest examples) and in case of problems - post a new question? You might get more luck on salesforce.stackexchange.com